# Is there an algorithm to determine the faces of a planar graph?

Tags: java, graph-theory

I'm working on a Java program to analyze graphs in various ways, specifically undirected graphs with weighted edges. I am now trying to, given a planar graph, determine its faces, a.k.a. the enclosed regions of "space" delimited by the graph's edges, but I really can't find an algorithm, or at least a comprehensible one, that could do this and I am struggling to implement one of my one.

Does someone have any idea?

PS : I should note that I do not have a solid basic grasp of graph theory

Comment: How are you representing your graph? How are you expecting the faces to be represented?

Comment: If X connected to all A,B,C,D,E,F and Y also connected to A,B,C,D,E,F then will be 6 pathes X-A-Y, X-B-Y, ... and they can be planed in ANY order. So you will get 6! = 720 planarizations. So, there is no stable faces in general case.

Comment: Walk along the edges, when you reach a vertex, always take (say) the most clock-wise edge.  When you return to your starting point, you’ve found a face... or the perimeter of the graph.  Repeat using a different edge/direction.  Each edge will border 2 faces (one for each direction you can move along the edge); when each edge has been added to two faces, you’ve found all the faces, plus the perimeter.  Perhaps not the most efficient algorithm, but it might get you started.

Answer (score 6):

The faces of a planar graph depend on having an embedding of a planar graph onto a surface. The issue arises that it is possible for there to be multiple embeddings of a planar graph.

For example:

```
   ----1----         ----1----      
  /   / \   \       /   / \   \     
 /   /   \   \     /   /   \   \    
2   3-----4   |   2   4-----3   |   
 \   \   /   /     \   \   /   /    
  \   \ /   /       \   \ /   /     
   ----5----         ----5----
```

The above graph can be embedded in two different ways with different faces for each.

So the first problem is to generate any single embedding; most efficient planarity tests will test planarity by generating an embedding (rather than using a less efficient method such as looking for forbidden minors) so you should be able to use any planarity test for this. The harder problem is to generate all possible embeddings - however, there is a solution for this in [Planarity Testing by Path Addition](https://archive.org/details/PlanarityTestingByPathAddition) (and contains Java code in the appendices to perform the planarity test, generate an embedding, cycle from one embedding of a biconnected graph to other embeddings and to generate a cyclic edge-order for each vertex for an embedding).

Once you have an embedding, you can represent the graph as a cyclic edge-order for each vertex. So, for the left-hand example:

```
Vertex Clockwise Edge-Order
------ --------------------
     1              2,5,4,3
     2                  1,5
     3                1,4,5
     4                1,5,3
     5              1,2,3,4
```

Then to find the faces, you just start at an edge and pick either clockwise or anti-clockwise and keep picking the next adjacent edge in that direction from successive vertices until you return to the starting edge:

```
Clockwise (2,1) -> (1,5) -> (5,2)
Clockwise (1,2) -> (2,5) -> (5,3) -> (3,1)
Clockwise (1,3) -> (3,4) -> (4,1)
Clockwise (1,4) -> (4,5) -> (5,1)
Clockwise (4,3) -> (3,5) -> (5,4)
```

And you have the faces (and each edge has been visited twice - once in each direction).